# How to remove long elements from a perl array?

Tags: arrays, perl, grep

I have a perl array that shouldn't have anything longer than 20 characters in it. Occasionally though, a longer string is input in error.

How can I "clean out" my perl array of these longer strings?  Is there a way to grep for length?  Something like..

```
@blurbs = grep([size<=20],@blurbs);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`length` gets the length of a string.

```
@blurbs = grep { length($_) <= 20 } @blurbs;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it could be using [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html)

Here is an example:

```
my @clean = map { length($_) <= 20 ? $_ : () } @blurbs;
```

Comment: IMHO, this is not a great use of `map`. You should use `grep` to *filter* a list, and `map` to *transform* a list. This `map` is a little confusing to read since it just implements a length filter.

Comment: @friedo Fair. I was golfing I guess.

Comment: Bad for golfing too; `grep` also uses fewer strokes. That said, this way of grepping is useful when you are doing more than just grepping. e.g. `map uc, grep cond($_), @a` can be written `map cond($_) ? uc : (), @a`. I'd use the former for readability, though.